# Spring Security Separate Login Information per WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

so the problem I am facing is the following.
I have 2 routes I want to protect: /api/v1 and /api/v2.
I have implemented the rest controller as a way to check which is the Principal currently used:

```
    @RestController
public class UserRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
    public Principal sayHello(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/api/v2/user")
    public Principal sayHello2(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to have different authorization mechanisms per route.
My current config is the following:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig{


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {              
            http    .antMatcher("/api/v1/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configurable
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    @Order(2)
    public static class ApiTokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;
        @Autowired
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails authorizationCodeResourceDetails;
        @Autowired
        ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProperties;

        /**
         * Method for creating filter for OAuth authentication
         *
         * @return OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter
         */
        private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter() {
            // Creating the filter for "/auth" url
            OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2Filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                    "/auth");

            // Creating the rest template for getting connected with OAuth service.
            // The configuration parameters will inject while creating the bean.
            OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(authorizationCodeResourceDetails,
                    oauth2ClientContext);
            oAuth2Filter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);

            // setting the token service. It will help for getting the token and
            // user details from the OAuth Service
            oAuth2Filter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(resourceServerProperties.getUserInfoUri(),
                    resourceServerProperties.getClientId()));

            return oAuth2Filter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v2/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/auth").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .addFilterAt(filter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior that I have observed is that if I access (and login) /api/v1/user then the principal used in /api/v2/user would be the same and vice-versa.
My question is the following: how can I avoid that? How is it possible to isolate the security types as much as possible between the 2 different routes?

Thanks

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to require /api/v1 http basic authentication and /api/v2 to require oauth authentication. Basically is it possible to have two completely separate security contexts for those 2 route paths

Comment: If I access /api/v1/user and authenticate using http basic I can see the corresponding principal. So far so good. If I then access /api/v2/user it considers that I am already logged in and doesn't initiate the oauth flow. Instead it shows the same principal

Comment: Exactly. I would want to initialize the oauth flow which is used when I first access /api/v2/user. Yeah probably with roles, this is the only possible solution right?

Comment: Great, so by using .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) it's working as intended.
I would personally find it a cleaner approach to secure on the controller level (using @Secured I guess) but also to specify which  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to be used per controller. Is it something that can be configured?